# How to delete 7 numbers after one number in a Javascript Array?

Tags: arrays, element, between

I have a little question jumping on my head.
How did you remove 7 elements of an array after one and so on.

Example.

FarmArray (Farmer, PIG, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,HORSE,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,DUCK,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,DONKEY,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,FOX...)

As you can see, discarding the first element "Farmer", between animals has 7 numbers, in this case I represented with numbers, but can be anything.

Now that I Wanna do is remove this 7 numbers between animals to the end of array.

I know about Array.splice(position,numbers to delete) I tried in a loop but probably Im doing a nonsense's .

How is the right way to do it?
Thanks

Thats the code I tried:

```
  for(var i=0; i<srclist.length; i++){
  srcList.splice(i+2, 7);
 };
  return srcList.join();
  };
```

Where spans is an array with all this elements.
With this For I walk through the array in order to delete the mentioned elements, and finally join the values of the array.

Comment: If you can paste the code you have tried, then people will be more likely / able to help you =]

Comment: Of course, I posted the code used for, I dunno whats wrong

Comment: Do you know about jsfiddle? It will allow others to easily test your code, and confirm a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` and `isNaN` as follows:

```
array =['Farmer', 'PIG','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','HORSE','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','DUK','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','DONKEY']
array.filter(isNaN);
```

The output is:

```
["Farmer", "PIG", "HORSE", "DUCK", "DONKEY"]
```

Comment: yes its a good option, but remember that only Using this values as examples. It will vary, instead of 1,2,3,4 should have Addresses, Phone Number, Date, Provider, etc.

Comment: @GerardoGarcía If so, you should change the title... Anyway, you can use any function to filter your data.